# Rephrase off topic language?

Tags: feature-request

The close reason

> This question does not appear to be about money or personal finance within the scope defined in the help center.

has the same problem as the logo, appearing to group *personal* only with *finance* and inviting arguments that "it's certainly about money."

Even if we can't get the area name or logo changed, can we find a way to rephrase this to make clear that our topic really is personal finance, period?

Comment: Very good idea IMO - and the moderators appear to have the means to change this directly, so let's just find an alternative wording with general agreement and then do it.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Agreed. Updated to the above. For the 20 second effort, I changed it, but am happy to read here if there's any more appropriate wording, and will update again.

Comment: Makes sense, rather than waiting for few days

Comment: But Money is not mentioned at all and so the zippy retort that the question is certainly about money in general even though it is not about Personal Finance  still applies. Nothing Personal, you understand? :-)

Answer (score 1):

People who argue along these lines when their question gets closed are willfully ignoring the "within the scope defined in the help center" part.  So I feel that no amount of changing the wording is going to solve that problem.

That being said, I don't actually have a problem with changing the wording, so if people feel like it might help, go for it.